# Auction starts in a specific time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I' making a penny auction site and i want the auction to start when it is scheduled in the model, what is the best way to do that?
    Should i try delayed jobs or there is a better way?

Comment: Fro what I know - things like delayedjob are the kind of solution you're looking for. This is a very general answer - but then, your question is very general :)
I'd suggest - go look at how to set up delayed job and give it a go - make a proof-of-concept. Then you'll have a good idea of whether or not, delayed-job will suit what you need.. and you'l have a better idea of how it works or does not work for you... which means you can come back to us with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

From what you stated, I don't think you need background jobs at all.

Remember that you need to work in the controller and in the view. It isn't enough just to hide the bid button in the view, you also need to block bidding on the controller.

In the controller, just do something like this:

```
def create
  if Time.zone.now > @auction.start_datetime && Time.zone.now < @auction.end_datetime
    @bid = Bid.new(params[:bid])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @bid.save
        format.html { redirect_to @bid, notice: 'Bid was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It is probably also good practice to, once a controller is hit after @auction.end_datetime, to set a "closed" attribute in the model, to make sure that clock changes in the server will not reopen already closed auctions.

Comment: I'm guessing that the auction needs to start regardless of whether somebody has gone to look at it and thus hit the server. For example, an email may need to be sent to all watchers saying the auction has started... this would need to be done at the scheduled time even if nobody is currently looking at the auction.

Comment: @TarynEast maybe, since i use rails 4.0, i can try websocket to have realtime auctions?

Comment: Hi @CrazyBarney - I don't know the answer... I just know that the above solution won't give you what you need.

Comment: @TarynEast I haven't see a reason to keep offline processes, as nothing will change/happen unless there is web connection, at least from what he stated. To the quetioner: what do you need to do that must happen outside of a user connection? "Opening" an auction can't just be modeled as the user being able to bid? If so, it can be fully done in the web framework. What else do you need to accomplish?

Comment: @MarcoPoli the questioner actually did say "at the time the auction starts" not "some time after the auction starts when the next person hits the webserver". Also: it's a developers job to look beyond what is said and see what the actual requirements ware likely to be. I can see several things that can potentially need to be done on the *actual* time that the auction starts, not to mention on the actual time that the auction ends... you don't want the final winner of the auction to only be informed of this when, some time later, somebody eventually comes back to look at the website.